# How to automatically populate Custom Item Field with data from a saved report in NetSuite?

Tags: workflow, netsuite

Software Platform - NetSuite

Goal - Run a weekly sales report. Use the data from that report to populate a custom item field on the item record (Kit item) in NetSuite.

Can this be done using a workflow or???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you try to write a Script or create a Workflow, I recommend you investigate NetSuite's ability to populate Custom Fields with Search Results.

Check out the Help page titled *Creating Custom Fields with Values Derived from Summary Search Results* for the details.

The basic process will involve creating a Saved Search that generates the data you need, then using the *Validation and Defaulting* tab on your Custom Item field to select the Search you created.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done using SuiteScript.  In your script, run a search, store the data as JSON, and submit the data to the item record.  You could submit the data into a single text field on the item record, but it would be better to create a Custom Record Type "Sales Report" which has a list/record field sourced from the item and with the "Record Is Parent" checkbox checked.  This will display your custom record on the item in a sublist.  Using a Custom Record Type will allow you to store the data over multiple iterations.  If you use a field on the item record it will be replaced each time you run the script.